# Vectors to grid of points - PHP

Tags: php

[image: Vector]

Points A and B got timestamps `$tA`, `$tB` and positions: `($xA,$yA)` and `($xB,$yB)`... What I need to do, is to convert that vector to grid of points of given size of grid field  - `$size` and to assign those poits proper times depending of what part of vector actually touches certain grid field.

Any way to do this fast?

Comment: A simple and straightforward algorithm would be `O(n^2)`. I can also think of some easy optimizations to significantly lower that. What do you have so far?

Comment: I am counting `a` and `b` in `y = ax+b` for those points and then checking value on every point that is border of grid field from `($xA,$yA)` to `($xB,$yB)`... and couting distance between "in" and "out" of field to determinate time... but it seems to be really slow, when I got million of those.

Answer (score 0):

Outline for `O(n^2)` algorithm:

1. Find out in which grid cell `A` and `B` are.
2. Now you have a bounding box of grid cells. If you A is (3,5) and B is (8,7) your bounding box is 5 by 2 cells
3. Now check for each grid cell if the vector intersects that grid cell.

Comment: Good idea, but ... times?